# Magento 2 Discount/Coupon Code Can Only Be Applied in Cart Page

Tags: magento2, checkout, coupon-codes

I am using **Magento 2.2.5** and if I apply a discount code in the cart this works OK. However, if I try to **apply discount code in payment/checkout page this does not work**.

Can anyone please advise a fix?

The text 'apply' doesn't even populate on the button.

Comment: Check network tab , when you apply dicsount this API calls V1/carts/mine/coupons/{coupon code} what is the response of that request

Comment: There is no restriction between cart and checkout for coupon. Coupon works on both.